# Numpy Pandas install fails with Sandbox violation on /dev/null

Tags: python, numpy, jenkins, pandas

I'm attempting to install numpy and pandas to a Jenkins server through  requirements.txt. However it's failing on the below 2 lines in the file.

```
numpy>=1.6.1
pandas==0.12.0
```

The output being:

```
setuptools.sandbox.SandboxViolation: SandboxViolation: open('/dev/null', 'w') {}

The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system

that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.
```

I've tried manually installing numpy and pandas however the install ignores that they're already satisfied and attempts and fails again.

Here's more of the console output: http://pastebin.com/gNScq75P

Can anyone see what's causing this? Many thanks

Comment: two thoughts: try to install it via superuser / root privileges. if it does not help you might check the ram the installation takes. numpy installation crashed one time at my ec2 instance, because of not enough memory available.

Comment: @ThomasKremmel When i installed manually i did so in the correct virtual env and with sudo. I just tried again and at the point of failure 3.5gb/8gb of ram was being used.

Comment: another thing I stumbled upon was while installing numpy and pandas via a requirements.txt and pip install requirements.txt it crashed (which was strange because numpy was placed before pandas in the req.txt9. while installing first only numpy manually (pip install numpy) followed by pip install pandas did worked for me.

Comment: this fixed it:

easy_install numpy
easy_install pandas

Answer (score 2):

Solution for future reference:

Reason for failed installation was that numpy and pandas have been installed from one requirements.txt via pip install requirements.txt. This failed, obviously ignoring the order of numpy and pandas. Manually installing first numpy and then pandas fixed the problem.

```
easy_install numpy
easy_install pandas
```

or

```
pip install numpy
pip install pandas
```

Alternatively one could create two requirements.txt files, the first one with numpy included and the second one with pandas included, and install them via:

```
pip install requirements_one.txt
pip install requirements_two.txt
```